# Android draw point

Tags: android, canvas, point

how to draw full circle or point with canvas? I using canvas and  path + paint classes

my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float eventX = event.getX();
    float eventY = event.getY();
    System.out.println(event.getAction());
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        path.addCircle(eventX, eventY, .1F, Path.Direction.CW);
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    // Schedules a repaint.
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: And are you actually drawing your `path` object in `onDraw` method?

Comment: yes. @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
 }

Answer (score 1):

Your paint must be "full", for that you must write this

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

then just draw your circle

```
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```

I hope it will be helpfull